# How to create a parametrised type in java with a type variable?

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection, types

The question title could be misleading, but I dont know how to summarise better what I want to acomplish. So please read through this body to undestand what I want to achive.

I have a method with a type parameter which gets some Class (eg MyClass). I need to create a **Type** of List and return it.

I thought this code would solve my problem. But the actual behaviour suprised me.

```
    public <T> Type getListClass(Class<T> cls) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.getType();
    return type;
}
```

Actual code:

[image]

Debugger:

[image]

I we inspect the **type2**, we can see that it has the rawType of **Arraylist** and typeArgument of **Integer** . Same I want to happen with my generic type.

But in the varibale **type** we observe a rawType of **Arraylist** and typeArgument of **T**. Instead T I want the to be a concrete Class (Like **Integer** or **MyCLass**). Basically I need a generic **List** **Type**, but *concrete* at the point of execution. Is there a way to acomplish that?

-----Edit 1-----

It is not a duplicate of this question: [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)
The answer there produces the same result as my code does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: @Milgo I does not. The answer there produces the same result as my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to type erasure, the `T` parameter isn't available at runtime inside `getListClass`, but you can use `TypeToken.where` (from [Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html)) to build the type using `cls`:

```
public <T> Type getListClass(Class<T> cls) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {}.where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, cls).getType();
    return type;
}
```

Comment: It looked promising, but suddenly I could not access the "where" method. Also the Documentation has not this method. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html

Comment: Are you using a different TypeToken class?

Comment: Got it, its guava https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html

Comment: My bad, I assumed you were using Guava, I should have mentioned it in the answer. Glad it worked in any case.